# How to set background-color with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to clarify this question: I am using the vue-router library to be able to create the routes of my project and I need to know how I can configure the background-color by routes.
I was planning to do it this way:

```
import meeting from '../components/meeting.vue'
import { colors } from 'vuetify/lib'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/meeting/:roomId',
    name: 'meeting',
    component: meeting,
    meta: {
      backgroundColor:colors.transparent ,
     }
  },  
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});
```

But it doesn't work, any suggestions please

Comment: How do you use `meta.backgroundColor`?

Comment: This way  `v-if="$route.meta.backgroundColor"`

Comment: Please share your relevant code where you are using $route.meta.backgroundColor

Comment: `<menuEscritorio  v-if="$route.meta.backgroundColor"></menuEscritorio>`

Answer (score 0):

You could watch the route in the component you wish to change the background color and insert the business logic there.

To create watchers you can do so by:

```
watch: {
$route.path: function (val) {
  this.backgroundColor = whateverYouWant
},
}
```

If you want this behavior to be used in other components too you can also create a mixin with this watcher.